# invalid use of flexible array ERROR in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct dish_t {
  const char *name;
  const char *cook;
  int maxIngredients;  
  bool tasted;
  Ingredient *ingredients[];
}* Dish;
```

And the following initialization function:

```
Dish dishCreate(const char* name, const char* cook, int maxIngredients) {

if (name == NULL || cook == NULL || maxIngredients <= 0 )
{
    return NULL;
}

Dish newDish=malloc(sizeof(*newDish));

newDish->name=malloc(strlen(name)+1);
newDish->name=name;
newDish->cook=malloc(strlen(cook)+1);
newDish->cook=cook;
newDish->maxIngredients=maxIngredients;

newDish->ingredients=malloc(maxIngredients*sizeof(Ingredient*));

newDish->tasted=false;
return newDish; 
}
```

Ingredient is also a struct.
and on this line

```
    newDish->ingredients=malloc(maxIngredients*sizeof(Ingredient*));
```

I get the error.
I'm trying to initialize an array of pointers to a struct...what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The struct member `ingredients` is an array of pointers, not a pointer. You cannot assign to an array in C; not to change its contents, and certainly not to change its address. The pattern `<array> = malloc(...)` makes no sense in C.

Just change the declaration to

```
Ingredient *ingredients;
```

Forget about flexible member; that's a memory allocation strategy that won't add to the semantics or quality of your program.

In some kinds of programs, flexible arrays at the end of a structure can be a useful 
optimization, since they reduce the number of calls to the allocator: a header structure plus some variable data can be allocated in a single `malloc` call and released in a single `free` call.

This doesn't achieve anything semantically interesting in the program, and naive use of this approach can make programs slower and waste memory, since two or more objects with flexible data at the end have to have their own copies of the data in situations where a program that uses a pointer could efficiently share that data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you try to make a flexible array of pointers, and then you try to create this using `malloc`, which is not what you're supposed to do.

With flexible arrays in a structure, you're supposed to make the *initial* allocation of the structure longer, to fit the number of elements in the array.

If you're going to use `malloc` for the array, you might as well use a normal pointer.

---

To explain what I mean:

```
typedef struct dish_t {
    ...
    Ingredient ingredients[];
}* Dish;

...

Dish myDish = malloc(sizeof(*myDish) + sizeof(Ingredient) * 10);
```

The above `malloc` allocates the structure and enough space for ten entries in the array.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be sizeof(Ingredient*) * 10 ? Because the array is an array of pointers not an array of sctructs.

Comment: @ArseniyPavlov Yes, if you really want an array of pointers. But in my mind it kind of defeats the purpose of having a flexible array to begin with.

Comment: It would makes sense if you point those pointers pointed to some already valid memory, then only a single malloc() would be required.